# html2canvas of a Highcharts chart not working fine on IE

Tags: javascript, highcharts, html5-canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to export a Highcharts chart and send it as email in js. To do that I used html2canvas library then added it to a jspdf object . everything worked fine on chrome and Firefox , however an empty pdf appeared when doing this on IE .
A pseudo-code  :

```
 var
    form = $('#main-content'),
    cache_width = form.width(),
    a4 = [100, 100]; 
    var canvas1 = html2canvas(form, {
        imageTimeout: 6000,
        removeContainer: true
    });
    canvas1.then(function (canvas) {

        var
        img1 = canvas.toDataURL("image/JPEG", 1.0);

        doc.addImage(img1, 'PNG', 0, 50, 440, 300);

    });



    Promise.all([canvas1]).then(function () {

        var pdfString = window.btoa(doc.output());
        var ob = {};
        ob.mail = mailsList;
        ob.title = title;
        ob.pdf = pdfString;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Charts/SendChart_ByEmail",
            data: JSON.stringify(ob)
        });
```

since IE does not support promises i used an external library (bluebird.js) but when rendering the div containing the chart , the result pdf is empty , however i tried to render another div not containing chart it worked .

is it a Highcharts bug ? bluebird issue ? any workaround ?

thank you,

Comment: Provide us with fully working example where this issue occurs. Thanks.

Comment: the issue is the pdf string sent to the ajax request , when working on IE the pdf string has l length of 20 Kb , however when working on chrome the string length is about 300kb ; i think this leaded to an empty pdf since the chart is not fully exported to canvas. @d_paul

Comment: the issue is from canvas.todatauri , the image generated is the empty div not containing the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was that canvas.todatauri does not work on IE if the div contains SVG .
so i used canvasg.. replaced the above code by :

```
 var chart = $('#main-content').highcharts();
        var svg = chart.getSVG({
            exporting: {
                sourceWidth: chart.chartWidth,
                sourceHeight: chart.chartHeight
            }
        });
        var mycanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvg(mycanvas, svg);
        var imgtest = mycanvas.toDataURL("image/JPEG");
        doc.addImage(mycanvas.toDataURL("image/JPEG"), 'PNG', 0, 50, 440, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue with IE11 while capturing the highchart charts which generates the svg charts. We used the technique of converting all svg images to canvas. Place the newly created canvas at svg. Now capture the dom and print/download it. Once print/download is done remove the canvas from dom again. It was working on chrome, FF and IE. We used the canvg npm module to convert svg to canvas as specified in the answer 1 by ibrahim noureddine